# Mongoose Schema: * in previous object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to store conversations between two users using MongoDB and the following schema.

```
`var messageSchema = new Schema({
    users: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
  {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }],
  user_msgs: [
  {
      is_sender: {}, //A user in users
      msg_body: String,
      created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
    }
  ]
});`
```

Is there a way to define is_sender so that it can only be a user from users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's some problems with this schema design. First of all, `messageSchema` looks more like a `conversationSchema` that contains lots of messages between two users. You probably want to have each message be a document. Also, the array type doesn't let you pick a length - you seem to want to restrict to a length of two in `users`. Just have two user fields in that case. The users can be embedded docs with a reference to a user and an optional `is_sender` field, or you can use the name of the user field itself to indicate who is the sender. I think a better schema would look like

```
var messageSchema = new Schema({
    sender: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    recipient : {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    msg_body: String,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

though this is speculative since I don't know your full use case.

Comment: A conversationSchema is exactly the plan and you got everything correctly. Using a schema like the one you wrote was the initial plan, but I couldn't figure out how to do queries to display the results like facebook chat.

Comment: How do you want to display it? Get the chats between two specific users? Just specify them both in a query to get all the results. You can use a restriction on created time as well.

Comment: For example:

`user1--->user2: Hello

user2--->user1: Hi!

user2--->user1: how are you doing?

user1--->user2: Great!`

Now, I can do db.messages.find({sender: user1} $where: {recipient: user2}), that'd display only:

`user1--->user2: Hello
user1--->user2: Great!`

How can I do queries so that I can display messages, the way it was sent originally.

Comment: Well, I guess you don't care for the query who was the sender and who wasn't then, so you could use an (always size 2) array and query for sender, recipient in the array, then sort by created time. You could also use an $or query and flip sender and recipient in the second clause.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `is_sender` shouldn't be a data type, but a function (which accepts a User and then runs a query to determine if that User is among the message users[]).

Perhaps you intend `is_sender` to return an array of users. In that case, one way wouldbe to impement `is_sender` as a function that runs a query to return the result (an array of Users).